# Sensu server logs filled with trash

Tags: logging, sensu

My sensu server logs are filled with trash nonstop that they reach file sizes of 3GB of the same log line.

Does anyone know how to debug this or find the source that is spamming the log file

Here is a sample of the log it is the same line over and over again

> {"timestamp":"2015-02-19T07:27:53.314313+0000","level":"error","message":"unknown
>   handler","handler_name":"graphite"}

Comment: You possibly have the handler configured but not installed.  Can you post your sensu configuration?  Documentation for  [Sensu Handlers](http://sensuapp.org/docs/0.12/handlers)

Comment: Which config file? I have many .json files one for each check and only one handler file for mails, I'm not using anything in my config files with  "graphite". Is there a specific file I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your handler is not defined but you're refering to it in your checks. You can define it by creating a handlers.json file in your /etc/sensu/conf.d/ directory (or where your sensu is installed).
Example:

```
{
    "handlers":{
        "graphite":{
            "type": "pipe",
            "command": ...
        }
    }
}
```